# How to test if key is UUID in clojure

Tags: clojure, uuid, midje

I'm trying to check whether a keyword is an UUID. It should look like this (which is not working):

```
{:70342332-7f99-417a-b864-9006de62ae05 {:a 1 b: 2}} => (just {uuid? {:a 1 :b 2}})
```

What are other ways to test it?

Using Midje 1.9.

Answer (score 2):

A clean way to archive what you need is this:

```
(defn keyword->uuid [kw]
     (try
      (java.util.UUID/fromString (name kw))
     (catch Exception e nil)))
```

If the keyword is convertible to the uuid object it will be converted and returned (note that any non-null return value is true so you can use this function both as a converter and a test). Otherwise the result would be nil:

```
user=> (keyword->uuid :dasdsa)
nil
user=> (keyword->uuid :70342332-7f99-417a-b864-9006de62ae05)
#uuid "70342332-7f99-417a-b864-9006de62ae05"
```

Answer (score -1):

Note that `:70342332-7f99-417a-b864-9006de62ae05` is *not* a UUID, it's a keyword. More generally speaking, a keyword is in Clojure a keyword, nothing else, regardless of what the string of characters looks like.

One way to achieve what you want is to take the `name` of the keyword and then read this string explicitly as a UUID:

```
user=> (uuid? (read-string (str "#uuid \"" (name :70342332-7f99-417a-b864-9006de62ae05) "\"")))
true
```

You can then [write your own Midje checker](https://github.com/marick/Midje/wiki/Writing-your-own-checkers) using this approach.

Comment: I think that the roundtrip to construct a string that is then read by the reader using the function for a tag is somewhat wasteful and non-obvious.  I'd rather use `java.util.UUID/fromString` directly.

Comment: You're right, I should have mentioned that option directly.